# jQuery .not() to exclude parents of certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for all divs with class=.task that aren't hidden by angular directives ng-show/ng-hide. However, I would also like to check the parent div is not hidden but I can not for the life of me figure out the proper selectors. There is no parent selector and .ng-hide isn't inherited from what I can tell.

This is what I have for finding divs that aren't hidden:

```
var tasks = $('div:first').find('.task').not('.ng-hide');
```

If it's not possible I guess I can repeat the ng-show on the children divs but it seems a cleaner if I could keep it solely on the parent div.

Comment: can you share html as well or a snippet or demo?

Comment: we need to see some HTML to be able to troubleshoot

Comment: have you tried the pseudo check ':visible'?

Comment: @ndimatteo THAT WAS IT! I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was the :visible selector because angular's ng-hide/ng-show work by setting display: none on the hidden element which :visible can react to. The solution...

```
var tasks = $('div:first').find('.task:visible');
```

Credit to @ndimatteo. If they post the answer I'll accept theirs.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `:not` selector like this.

```
var tasks = $('div:first').find('.task:not(".ng-hide")');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a selector for the parents in JQuery, called `parent()`.